# Angular JS xeditable Grid not working inside form tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I am using Angular xEditable inline grid. 
https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row 
Each row contains multiple controls. 
When xEditable grid is put inside form tag it is not working.

```
<form>
..
    xeditable grid code 
..
</form>
```

Update: Refer this http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/
In that if you add form tag in html code it doesn't work, in my requirement i will have to put a form tag in the page containing grid

Comment: Add more details please.

Comment: i have added additional details.

Comment: To create editable row in table you should place editable elements in cells with **e-form** attribute pointing to **form's name**. **The form itself can appear later** (e.g. in last column) but it will work. Don't forget to add editable-form attribute to the form. The form behavior is absolutely the same as described in Editable form section

Comment: In my case that grid is part of a page containing form tag, so if you add a form tag in that example outside the outerdiv <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">, it doesnt work. Edit that example by adding from tag.. Thanks